# CSS and JS not loading

Tags: javascript, css, php-5.5, magento-2.1.4

When I run in my terminal: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

which is supposed to be the fix for css and js not loading, I get this:

> PHP Parse error:  parse error in
>   /Magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php
>   on line 93

I'm on a Mac using the main local web server. Not MAMP. Please someone tell me how to fix this before I give up on Magento.

PHP version 5.5.30, and I've changed root links in db to 127.0.0.1, Magento version 2.1.4 with data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your PHP version to at least 5.6.5. You can see in the [DevDocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html#php) that Magento no longer supports PHP 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

This is the function that assert error in your case.

```
protected function createObject($type, $args)
{
    return new $type(...array_values($args));
}
```

You can see three dots (`...`) in the call `new $type(...array_values($args));`. This three dots token is know as [*Variable Argument List*](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) which is available only for php versions greater than 5.6.

So what you need to do here is upgrade your php version `5.6.5` or later as per the M2 version you are using.

If you can upgrade to php 7.x version, then that will be great.